# When should I use a class and when should I use a function?

Tags: python

When is a class more useful to use than a function? Is there any hard or fast rule that I should know about? Is it language dependent? I'm intending on writing a script for Python which will parse different types of json data, and my gut feeling is that I should use a class to do this, versus a function.

Comment: This is a subjective question.

Comment: these are two different things. a class is "what it is", a function is "what it does". a toaster is a class. and the toaster has a "toast the bread" function

Comment: it IS language dependent (no class if the language doesn't support class, not necessarily oop since oop can be done without class), but this question is subjective

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a class when your routine needs to save state. Otherwise a function will suffice.

Comment: Even if you need to save state, a function can be used because they can have arbitrary attributes. One difference though, is that it's easier to have create and maintain multiple instances of a class than it is of a function.

Comment: However, there's also no convenient way for a function to refer to itself.

Comment: Can it not just use `<func name>.attribute`?

Comment: Sure. But that requires the function to know its own name. `self.attribute` is much more convenient.

Comment: Knowing its own name isn't a problem if there's only one of them. Which was the point of my original comment, namely that needing to save state isn't the critical factor because functions are capable of doing that, too. Rather, it's whether you'll ever need to have more than one in an independent state at a time.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I think that isn't language-dependent (if the language permit you to define classes and function as well).

As a general rule I can tell you that a Class wrap into itself a *behaviour*. So, if you have a certain type of *service* that you have to implement (with, i.e. different functions) a class is what you're lookin' for.
Moreover classes (say object that is more correct) has state and you can instantiate more occurrences of a class (so *different* objects with *different* states).

Not less important, a class can be inearthed: so you can overwrite a specific behaviour of your function only with small changes.

Comment: how can you play with class in a language without class support?

Comment: @LeleDumbo: is evident that isn't a language-dependent matter IF the language support function definition. But this is elementary, without the need for more details in the answer

Comment: +1 I like this explanation best: It's all about encapsulation of behaviour. All the other people talking about states only miss an important point I think.

Answer (score 1):

the class when you have the **state** - something that should be persistent across the calls

the function in other cases

exception: if your class is only storing couple of values and has a single method besides __init__, you should better use the function

Answer (score 1):

For anything non-trivial, you should probably be using a class.  I tend to limit all of my "free-floating" functions to a utils.py file.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* language-dependent.

Some languages, like Java, insist that you use a class for everything. There's simply no concept of a standalone function.

Python isn't like that. It's perfectly OK - in fact recommended - to define functions standalone, and related functions can be grouped together in modules. As others have stated, the only time you really want a class in Python is when you have state that you need to keep - ie, encapsulating the data within the object.