# How do I correctly create methods in a Class

Tags: python, class, instance

I am trying to force myself to understand how to use classes.  My code has gotten longer and messier.  I am hoping that using classes will help me clean it up some

```
from lxml import html

Class Header(object):
    def __init__(self,file_reference)
        self.header =  open(file_reference).read()

    def filing_type(self):
        tree = html.fromstring(self)
        for element in tree.iter():
            if element.tag == 'type':
                return element.text.strip()
```

so I have a reference to a particular file

```
 myref = 'correct_file_path'
 test_header = Header(myref)
```

when I do a dir(test_header) I see my filing_type function in the list.  However when I run

```
 test_header.filing_type()
```

I get a TypeError

```
 TypeError: 'Header' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `tree = html.fromstring(self.header)`?

Comment: @Blender thanks I had not tried that variation but it worked however zhangyangyu provided the answer so I have to give it to him.

Comment: Also, does your class do anything other than store one variable and store methods?

Comment: I really want to ask the question - should I use a class for this problem - I think that is getting at what you are asking but I am certain the question would be closed in a millisecond or two.  I perform lots of operations on these files and so right now I thought I would have all the methods in a class

Comment: No, it's a decent question. It's hard to say without your current code, but it doesn't seem like you need a class.

Comment: Thanks I was working on the question and came across these [Q-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331719/when-should-i-use-a-class-and-when-should-i-use-a-function), [Q-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076348/should-i-use-a-class-python) and they helped so thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `tree = html.fromstring(self.header)`. And it seems your `return` in `filling_type` is wrong because it will only return the first tag's contents(Maybe you just want this). Maybe you could use a list to store all the type tags or use yield.